# Чи правильно говорити "одинарні лапки"?

Tags: вживання-слів, правопис

> Є одинарні і подвійні лапки.

Правильно?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Запитання, які не демонструють **спроби автора самостійно відповісти** на нього, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть [edit] у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням. Ще раз, ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Comment: Чи могли б Ви розписати докладніше: що саме схиляє Вас сумніватися в цьому?

Comment: ніби нічого, просто хотів правильно вживати : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/odynarnyj) знаходимо:

> **ОДИНА́РНИЙ**, а, е. Який складається з однієї частини; не подвійний. Зачинені віконниці мало захищали від морозу, і одинарні рами вкрилися товстим шаром льоду (Олександр Бойченко, Молодість, 1949, 124).

Оскільки існують так звані [одинарні лапки](http://404.in.ua/2013/03/lapky-v-ukrajinskij-ta-inshyh-movah/), які не є подвійними, то цей термін нормативно вживати.